# Как организовать синхронизацию данных между двумя приложениями

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение на Java под Windows - это небольшая програмка с БД, чтение, запись и отображение данных. Хочу написать точно такую же только под android, которое можно будет поставить на все домашние телефоны.

Вопрос - как мне проще организовать синхронизацию данных между ними. Хотелось бы конечно, чтобы это было организовано через сервер в интернете, т.е. чтобы можно было сохранить где-то, а остальные устройства синхронизируются по мере необходимости, но я не знаю есть возможность держать где-то БД бесплатно. Приложение не коммерческое, только для домашнего пользования, поэтому рассматриваю только бесплатные варианты.

Например, данное приложение будет установлено на 5 телефонов, на одном из них кто-то добавил (изменил) какую-то запись.
Куда проще всего выгрузить эти данные, чтобы остальные могли их загрузить, по мере необходимости (завтра, через месяц и т.д.)?

Comment: Для сохранения простого списка контактов вам достаточно иметь один файл который содержит все данные.  Держите данные в алфавитном порядке и периодически отправляйте на сервер для синхронизации данных. Не усложняйте задачу сделайте проще.

Comment: я понимаю, что вообще любую базу можно сохранить в одном фале, вопрос как его проще передать остальным. Я добавил в пример в вопросе

Comment: Сделайте один веб сервис, и чтоб все с ним синхронизировались. По факту сервис будет получать файл для обновления и передавать обновленный.

Comment: Есть возможность сделать такое бесплатно в интернете? Или только на домашнем компе? Я и хочу узнать как это можно сделать. Вроде как можно на heroku залить, но там очень малый объем дают бесплатно.  На почтовых ящиках по 20 гиг выделяют, но я не в курсе можно туда организовать доступ програмно, дают они какой-то API.

Comment: доступ на Email ервера организуется через POP3 или IMAP протоколы. Многие сервера предоставляют к нему доступ. Только это не нужно вам.  А то что вам не хватит бесплатных сервисов на heroku меня просто удивляет. Вы сделайте сначала что нибудь потом будите говорить что места мало. Вы создаете себе преграды даже не начав работать

Comment: я просто вижу какого размера уже локальная БД, а она будет только увеличиваться, одно приложение то у меня работает. Они там до гига уменьшили бесплатный объем